# Como configurar Eslint en Astro

Tags: javascript, eslint

Estoy intentando configurar Eslint en astro pero no lo logro, a continuación les diré los pasos que seguí luego de iniciar el proyecto

```
pnpm create astro@latest
npm install --save-dev eslint eslint-plugin-astro
```

luego creé el archivo `.eslintrc.js` con la siguiente configuración:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  extends: [
    // ...
    "plugin:astro/recommended",
  ],
  // ...
  overrides: [
    {
      // Define the configuration for `.astro` file.
      files: ["*.astro"],
      // Allows Astro components to be parsed.
      parser: "astro-eslint-parser",
      // Parse the script in `.astro` as TypeScript by adding the following configuration.
      // It's the setting you need when using TypeScript.
      parserOptions: {
        parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
        extraFileExtensions: [".astro"],
      },
      rules: {
        // override/add rules settings here, such as:
        // "astro/no-set-html-directive": "error"
      },
    },
    // ...
  ],
}
```

luego de ello guardé en vscode para ver si me realizaba los cambios de acuerdo a las reglas pero no los hizo, me pueden ayudar por favor?